# A question about Integral and Measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Lets consider the integral $\int_{0}^{1}logxd\mu$ where measure $\mu$ is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure. What about convergence of this integral? Thanks.

Comment: If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent measures, then the Radon-Nikodym derivative vanishes nowhere, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe yes, maybe no.  Let Lebesgue measure be $\lambda$.  If $\mu=\lambda$, the integral is convergent.  On the other hand, if
$$
\mu(A)=\int_A \frac{1}{|x|} d\lambda(x) \qquad \text{for all measurable sets } A,
$$
then it's not.

Comment: In the second example are the measures $\mu$ and $\lambda$ equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent.